Gaming and art Ubuntu help
I going to Ubuntu as my PC is stuck to win10 cause it's physically unable to go to win11. As the title says I wanna know of a desktop style Ubuntu for gaming and art.

Download a wallpaper for your favorite game and provide a link to it in your question. Then we can search for a theme to match it.

What do you mean by "desktop style Ubuntu for gaming and art"? Gaming or art don't specifically relate to any particular desktop style, they are upto individual's tastes.

You can find a lot of Ubuntu compatible themes at https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/
